# Creating popup menu in Qt for QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` in the main UI of my program. I'd like to show popup menu when user right clicks on the cells of the table and take appropriate action when an option is selected from the menu.

I am using Qt Creator 1 (Qt version 4.5). How can I do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check out the [customContextMenuRequested](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal to get the event, and use a [QMenu](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html) for the menu itself. Use [QTableView::indexAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#indexAt) to find out what, if any, cell was clicked based on the coordinates given to the signal and take the appropriate action when a menu item is clicked.

Comment: You will need to call menu.exec(const QPoint&) to display it. Make sure you translate it to the appropriate coordinates:

menu.exec(mapToGlobal(point), 0)

Comment: Or just use menu.exec(QCursor::pos()) http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qmenu.html#exec

Comment: Context menu may be called from the keyboard shortcut, so cursor position is not always the correct point of call.